# Query results do not load properly (Node.js / Postgresql)

Tags: javascript, heroku

I am having a bit of trouble understanding why all the queries cannot load 
without `setTimeout()` or are loading partially.
This is the code using `setTimeout()` / MINIMAL_QUERY_TIMEOUT = 58 / :

```
router.get('/test', (request, response, next)=>{
    var db_user1 = loadUserByUniqueProperty("username", "CoolUsername12");
    // I really dont know why, but it's not working any other way; 58 is the minimal timeout
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(db_user1);
      var messages = getAllMessagesForCurrentUser(db_user1.db_id);
      setTimeout(()=>{
         console.log(messages);
      }, MINIMAL_QUERY_TIMEOUT*3); // <-------- PART 2

    }, MINIMAL_QUERY_TIMEOUT); // <---------- PART 1

    response = setResponseTypeToTextHtml(response);
    response.send("Loaded");
});
```

And the output is just fine:

```
User {
  names: 'Some Weird Names',
  username: 'CoolUsername12',
  password: undefined,
  email: 'supermail@mail.com',
  address: 'Sofia, Lyulin 7, blok 723',
  country: 'Bulgaria',
  allMessagesIds: [],
  unreadMessagesIds: [],
  sentMessagesIds: [],
  isOnline: true,
  password_hash: '400f2078117282506e65969aaf77eea338cd05d4eb2fde26289c5007d489b5a7',
  db_id: 7
}
[
  sentMessages: [
    {
      id: 2,
      content: 'Hello brato!',
      timesent: 2019-12-11T14:28:08.980Z,
      isanswered: false,
      senderid: 7,
      recieverid: 7
    }
  ],
  recievedMessages: [
    {
      id: 2,
      content: 'Hello brato!',
      timesent: 2019-12-11T14:28:08.980Z,
      isanswered: false,
      senderid: 7,
      recieverid: 7
    }
  ],
  unreadMessages: [
    {
      id: 2,
      content: 'Hello brato!',
      timesent: 2019-12-11T14:28:08.980Z,
      isanswered: false,
      senderid: 7,
      recieverid: 7
    }
  ]
]
```

The queries code:

```
function getAllMessagesForCurrentUser(userId){
  var ret = Array();
  var psql_for_sent = "SELECT * FROM message_test WHERE senderid = " + userId + ";";
  var psql_for_recieved = "SELECT * FROM message_test WHERE recieverid = " + userId + ";";
  var psql_for_not_answered = "SELECT * FROM message_test WHERE recieverid = " + userId + " AND isanswered = 'f';"
  client.query(psql_for_sent).then(
    res=>{
        ret['sentMessages'] = res.rows;
    }
    ).catch(err=>console.error(err));

  client.query(psql_for_recieved).then(
    res =>{
    ret['recievedMessages']= res.rows;
    }
  ).catch(err=>console.error(err));

  client.query(psql_for_not_answered).then(
    res=>{
    ret['unreadMessages']= res.rows;
    }
  ).catch(err=>console.error(err));
  return ret;
}

function loadUserByUniqueProperty(property, property_content){
  var user = new User();
  var psql = "SELECT * FROM users_test WHERE "+ property + " = '" + property_content + "';"
  client.query(psql).then(
              res=>{    
                        res = res.rows[0];
                        user.setNames(res['names']);
                        user.setAddress(res['address']);
                        user.setCountry(res['country']);
                        user.setEmail(res['email']);
                        user.setUsername(res['username']);
                        user.isOnline = true;
                        user.setPassword(undefined);

                        user.password_hash= res['password_hash'];
                        user.db_id = res['id'];
                    }).catch(err=>console.error(err));
  return user; 
}
```

But when PART 1 (marked above) is omitted, or PART 2 (also marked above) is lesser or also omitted, I get  `undefined` as output, or partial output ( like `recievedMessages` or 
`unreadMessages` are missing);
So, the question is: How can i avoid that? How can I be sure they are all loaded when i need them?

P.S.: I am using a remote **heroku** database (postgres), and tables contain a maximum of 2 rows each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using async await. The reason why the timeout works is because it takes some time for your promise to resolve, IE receive data from postgres.

```
router.get('/test', async (request, response, next)=>{
    const db_user1 = loadUserByUniqueProperty("username", "CoolUsername12");
    const messages = await getAllMessagesForCurrentUser(db_user1.db_id);


});
```

Comment: I tried, but i still get undefined - I marked loadUserBy...() and getAllMessages..() as  async

Comment: I found the solution, i just had to await for all the queries :) Thanks for showing me the right direction